# VB.Net Treeview "Rollback"

Tags: vb.net, recursion, treeview

I am populating a tree view dynamically so I do not know the amount of levels I may have.

Is there a way to rollback to the previous level? Here is a sample of my code:

```
Private Sub RecursiveTreeAssembly(FileName As String, node As TreeNodeCollection)
    'Sets sFileNamePath to correct path value
    FileNameToFilePath(FileName)

    'Start SolidEdge
    StartSolidEdge()

    'Open document
    OpenSolidEdgeDocument(sFileNamePath)

    'Get the parts list for the opened document (FileName)
    partList = clsPartInformation.GetAll()

    'Populate tree View
    If partList.Count > 0 Then
        'PartsList retrieved, close document
        CloseSolidEdgeDocument(FileName)

        'Go through all part lists and display them in tree view
        For i As Integer = 0 To partList.Count - 1
            'Is it Assembly, Parametric, Material, Part to buy
            If IsAssembly(partList(i).Part_No) Then
                node(iterator).Nodes.Add(partList(i).Part_No)
            ElseIf IsMaterial(partList(i).Part_No) Then
                node(iterator).Nodes.Add(partList(i).Part_No)
            ElseIf IsPart(partList(i).Part_No) Then
                node(iterator).Nodes.Add(partList(i).Part_No)
            End If

            tvDessins.ExpandAll()
        Next
    End If

    'Go through tree view to populate it
    While iterator < tvDessins.Nodes(0).Nodes.Count
        If rollback Then
            node = tvDessins.Nodes
            currFileName = node(0).Nodes.Item(iterator).Text
        Else
            currFileName = node(iterator).Nodes.Item(0).Text
        End If

        If IsAssembly(currFileName) Then
            rollback = False
            'Call itself again
            RecursiveTreeAssembly(currFileName, node(0).Nodes)
        Else
            'Rollback nodes
            rollback = True
        End If

        iterator += 1
    End While
End Sub
```

tvDessin is my tree view. In the following code, I will iterate through a tree view that has been given some items recursively. My parts list contains the part number, that works great.

It is during my rollback that I set the tree nodes to the beginning:
node = tvDessins.Nodes

Instead of simply going to the parent node ... That's what I'm looking to achieve!

Thank you, sorry for such a long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here's the answer:

```
If rollback Then
    currFileName = node.Item(0).Parent.Nodes(iterator).Text 'retrieves parent
Else
    currFileName = node(iterator).Nodes.Item(0).Text
End If
```